# algorithm similar to 'assignment task'

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

Here is the assignment problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_assignment_problem

I have a similar task, but can't find the algorithm. 
We have m tasks, n laborers, m>n. When task is done, the laborer takes the next one (if there is free one). If task is taken by some laborer, no one else can take it.  Each laborer has his own speed: V1..Vn, each task has its own 'volume' - W1..Wm. So, i need to distribute tasks between laborers with the goal of minimization of time doing all tasks.

Please help me to find an algorithm or how this problem is named.)

Comment: It's a scheduling problem (minimize the makespan on (I assume) uniformly related machines).

Comment: @DavidEisenstat thank you, seems that's it.. found some articles on uniformly related machines, but it's not very easy to understand the contents and even whether the problem is the same..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a likely np-complete variation of the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem.  I would therefore not worry about an exact algorithm.

Assuming that the tasks are independent, my first try would be a greedy heuristic.  Given an estimate of finishing time, assign to each worker at all points the longest task that they can finish before that finishing time.  Now do a binary search to find the shortest finishing time that you can get away with.  Your initial upper time is the time for the fastest worker to do everything.  Your initial lower time is the time for all of the workers to complete that much work if all are working at the same time.

This is clearly not always going to be perfectly optimal.  But it should work reasonably well.

Comment: thank you for a reply, but i think it's not a bin-packing problem. 
Scheduling problem, as mentioned before, is more likely.
\Imagine we (me and you) have 3 different cakes) You can eat faster than me. And we should distribute cakes between us. So, depending on sizes and speeds, the fastest way may be you eat the largest one, and i - the two others, or vice versa, or even you eat all the three, cause i eat very-very slowly )

Comment: @MichaelLevin Flip the question from scheduling to, "Can we complete this work in 5 hours?"  Now workers can be viewed bins of size "the work they could do", and the question becomes whether you can distribute items (jobs) to those bins such that no bin goes over the limit.  That's the bin-packing connection.

My suggested solution makes this connection explicit.  I am suggesting a binary search for the shortest finishing time.  But each step in that search involves solving a bin-packing problem.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is scheduling jobs on parallel, uniformly related machines so as to minimize the makespan. There's a polynomial-time approximation scheme due to [Hochbaum and Shmoys](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/SFCS.1985.63) (Using dual approximation algorithms for scheduling problems: Theoretical and practical results, 1988). btilly is right that the bin-packing problem is closely related; the analyses of both Hochbaum--Shmoys and the previous best approximation MULTIFIT are based on techniques pioneered for bin packing.